# Android nested requests for SimpleCursorAdapter and regexps

Tags: android, regex, sqlite, listview

In my application I need to access data stored in a SQLite database to create a list of names+icons.

I have two tables in my database :
One contains the Name Column (and a lot of other columns for details), but this name column contains text with the ID of a text stored in another table (dictionnary).
It looks like this :

the main table :

```
ClassID | Name                    | ...
1       | "foo <$>9973</> bar"    | ...
```

the dictionnay table :

```
ID      | Content
9973    | "Name of the item"
```

The thing I would need would be to retrieve automatically the name from the dictionnary before it is used to generate the **ListView**. And It would be best if the dictionnay calls weren't made asynchronously...

I need to apply something similar to the php fonction **preg_replace_callback** to match the   pattern and look for the corresponding text in the dictionnary.

I've seen some things with setViewValue but I'm not sure how to use it.

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks

EDIT :
To be a bit clearer, the output should be in my example :

```
"foo Name of the item bar"
```

Comment: change the Name column to contain  only text,  place the id in a separate column

Comment: How does it solve my issue? I still need to replace it in the string, and to know where it is in the string...
Plus it would require prealable modifications of the table, which I can't afford since I'm not the one generating it

Comment: ok,  so use a ViewBinder or (for more advanced devs) a custom CursorWrapper

Comment: or instead of CursorWrapper created by you, use a CursorFactory passed to a custom SQLiteOpenHelper constructor, now the wrapper will be created automatically

Comment: yes,  after quick checking the CursorFactory is the best way to go...

Comment: Thanks for the indications but I ended up using a SimpleAdapter, that way it will be easier to sort and filter the data I hope !

Comment: SimpleAdapter to map the data from sqlite db? ok, its your code...

Comment: Well I only need to query it once as the data never changes, it's probably not the right way to do it but surely the easiest and fastest to implement for me, as I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

As I was having trouble using SimpleCursorAdapter, I finally chose to use a SimpleAdapter and generate the List via my dabatabase helper.

the function to generate the list :

```java
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getCharList(){
    if(list.isEmpty()) {
        Cursor mdbCursor;
        mdbCursor = this.getReadableDatabase()
                           .query("job", neenter code herew String[]{"ClassID _id", "Name"},
                                  null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mdbCursor != null) {
            while (mdbCursor.moveToNext()) {
                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String Name;
                temp.put("_id", mdbCursor.getString(0));
                Name=mdbCursor.getString(1);
                //I do my stuff on Name here
                temp.put("Name", Name);
                list.add(temp);
            }
            mdbCursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Then I use it this way in my fragmentlist :

```java
db=new CharDatabase(getActivity());
String[] fromColumns = {"Name"};
int[] toViews = {R.id.charName};
mSimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                                   db.getCharList(),
                                   R.layout.row,
                                   fromColumns,
                                   toViews);
```

This way I can easily filter elements, and if I need to sort it I can do it with the usual sorting functions and then call :
    mSimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();